# python opencv LBPHFaceRecognizer stuck forever while reading models of huge size

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

I have created a face recognition model in `python` using `opencv` and `LBPHFaceRecognizer`. The model  training and prediction works absolutely fine upto 100 different faces(For each person I capture 50 images).

However, after training the model for 300 different people, the opencv  is stuck forever while reading the model file for prediction.

The model is an `xml` file of size 9 GB.

Below is my code(partial):

```
import cv2
import os

def read_image_data():

    face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    model_path = os.path.join(model_path, 'model_file.xml')
    face_recognizer.read(model_path)  # The program gets stuck here and doesn't proceed. No error 
    predict_model(face_recognizer)


def predict_model(face_recognizer):
   ....
```

Library Versions:

```
opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.40
opencv-python==4.4.0.40
```

I have tried in both `windows 10` and `ubuntu 20.04`.

how do I proceed further about this? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you share the `read`function?

Comment: `read()` is the built-in read function I get from the `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()` object. Not a user defined one.